# adding space between images

Tags: html, css

How can I add some space to the following images 
Meaning that I want horizontal space in between the following images

```
<p class="menusomething">In-game Imagery</br>
<a href="R.jpg"><img src="age1.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>          </a></br>
<a href="Re2.jpg"><img src="age2.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>   </a></BR>
<a href="Ri.jpg"><img src="Re3.jpg" width="200" height="150"/></a></BR>
<a href="Ri4.jpg"><img src="e4.jpg" width="200" height="150"/></a></BR>
</p>
```

and the css code

```
p.menusomething{background: white;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 200px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 200px;}
```

Answer (score 7):

you were targeting the container of your images, not the images themselves.
to fix this, simply add any of the following CSS lines to your file

```
p.menusomething a>img
{
   margin-top:20px; /*to have the space above the image*/
   margin-bottom:20px; /*to have the space under the image*/
}
```

just one of them should do the job, let me know if this is what you need.

check this Live demo for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/3jApT/3/

Comment: glade to hear that, kindly consider to mark it as answer if it has fixed your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

add hspace="20"  for a foto's

```
<p class="menusomething">In-game Imagery</br>
<a href="R.jpg"><img src="age1.jpg" width="200" height="150" hspace="20" />          </a></br>
<a href="Re2.jpg"><img src="age2.jpg" width="200" height="150" hspace="20" />   </a></BR>
<a href="Ri.jpg"><img src="Re3.jpg" width="200" height="150" hspace="20" /></a></BR>
<a href="Ri4.jpg"><img src="e4.jpg" width="200" height="150" hspace="20" /></a></BR>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p.menusomething a img {
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p.menusomething img 
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menusomething img {
 display:block;
 margin:10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.menusomething > img:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 28px; // if images are aligned vertically
  margin-right: 28px; // if images are aligned horizontally
}
```